# Can anyone recommend a reference where the collatz conjecture is viewed as a combinatorics problem?

Tags: nt.number-theory, infinite-combinatorics, collatz-conjecture

It occurs to me that the question about whether non-trivial cycles exist for the [collatz conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) can be restated as these two questions (details on how this relates to the collatz conjecture can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4417018/48606)):

- Is there a general method for determining how many distinct values of $t_1, t_2, \dots, t_k$ exist for a given $k$ such that:

  - $t_k > t_{k-1} > \dots > t_2 > t_1 > 0$
  - $2\left(2^{t_k} - 3^k\right) < 3^{k-1} + \sum\limits_{i=1}^{k-1}3^{k-1-i}2^{t_i}$
- Would it follow that as $k$ increases, the number of distinct values approaches infinity?

It seems to me that if the number of distinct values approaches infinity and distinct values have sufficient variability, then the collatz conjecture is most likely not true.  If the number of distinct values has a finite limit, then the collatz conjecture may well be true.

Are there any well known papers that investigate the collatz conjecture from this viewpoint?

Intuitively, it seems to me that one of the following must be true:

- there is only a finite number of distinct values of $3^{k-1} + \sum\limits_{i=1}^{k-1}3^{k-1-i}2^{t_i} > 2\left(2^{t_k} - 3^k\right)$
- there is an infinite number of distinct values but all are relatively prime to $2^{t_k} - 3^k$
- the collatz conjecture has at least one non-trivial cycle

Are there any well-known results that address this approach?

Comment: im sure all of this has been explored before

Comment: Thanks.  I'll delete if the question score stays negative and there is no answer.  It was suggested that I post it here from MSE.  I am trying to find out more information about what's been well explored.  I just want to find the papers and start reading up.  :-)

Comment: Quite some time since I looked at it but I believe some details of that can be found in Lagarias’ work(and certainly those of others I can’t recall now).  See for instance  https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0309224.pdf and https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/Lagarias3-23.pdf

Comment: Hmm, didn't mention this here so far (why did I forget?) For the discussion in MSE I made a short exploration, put on my homepage, see https://go.helms-net.de/math/collatz/CombinatoricalCountForNumberOfCyclicOrbits.pdf for some heuristics and considerations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lagarias' bibliographies give some references from where you might search forward. For instance see this
[image]
This is from the year-2004 version; Lagarias updated this up to version 2011; the Lagarias bibliogrphies are downloadable from the net.

---

Update (7'22): Just found an old downloaded article

```
Maurice Margenstern and Yuri Matiyasevich   

Abstract:
We show how the 3 x + 1  conjecture can be expressed
in the language of arithmetical formulas with 
binomial coefficients.
```

```
e-mail: margens@antares.iut.univ-metz.fr   
e-mail: yumat@pdmi.ras.ru      
URL: http://logic.pdmi.ras.ru/~yumat
```

This is of 1998; don't know whether the URL or the email is still working; maybe it is only tangential to your question, but thought it might be of interest from a wider perspective in the combinatorical context.

Comment: Thanks Gottfried.  Jack L in his comment above provides links to bibliographies.

Comment: Thanks, @LarryFreeman for notification. I'll be little available next 3 weeks but shall be back then. Btw. thumbs up for your meta-thread...